# When showing surjectivity, why must only a single element showing the behavior be found?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

The definition from my textbook states the following definition to show surjectivity:

> To show the function $f : A \rightarrow B$ is surjective:
>
> > Suppose $b \in B$
> >
> > [Prove there exists $a \in A$ for which $f (a) = b$.]
>
> In the second step, we have to prove the existence of an a for which
>   $ f (a) = b$ . For this, just finding an example of such an a would suffice.

What doesn't make sense to me is why does it only need to be proven that there exists one element from $A$ for which the function $f(a)=b$? I would think that surjectivity would need to be proven for every element, and not just a single example. Is this not just showing that a single element from the domain maps to a single element from the codomain?

I must be interpreting things incorrectly, what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Well, as $b$ can be *any* element of $B$ (there's no specification  about it), it is proved for every element indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show it for every $b\in B$.

However, at each time you're looking at one of the $b$s, you only need to find one $a$ that hits *that* $b$.

Typically the proof will start with "Let $b$ be an arbitrary element of $B$ ..." which means that you're claiming that the procedure you're describing will work *no matter which* $b$ you apply it to -- so in order to find an $a$ for *every* $b$ you can simply repeat that procedure once for each $b$. (This works because the $a$ you find is allowed to depend on $b$ -- you're not being asked for one $a$ that *by itself* hits everything in $B$).